# json array parse in php

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can a JSON start with [?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034444/can-a-json-start-with)

This is an abbreviated version of my problem. 
My `json` output has comma separated groups, how can i make this work?

```
$json = '{"foo": "12345"}, {"foo": "6789"}, {"bar": "001100"}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj[0]->{'foo'};
```

currently it gives me an error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: You need to wrap your input in `[` and `]` to make it a valid array in JSON notation.

Comment: you can use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json string. It's usefull sometime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your list into javascript array:

```
$json = '{"foo": "12345"}, {"foo": "6789"}, {"bar": "001100"}';
$json = '[' . $json . ']';
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj[0]->{'foo'};
```

Comment: yep: http://codepad.org/3o3KdnfN