# JSON: Simple basic Quiestion about its structures

Tags: json

I've got a really small question about JSON objects. I've just read that:

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>   list, or associative array.
>
> An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

Now I have this example JSON object

```
{
     "firstName": "Peter",
     "lastName": "Meier",
     "age": 25,
     "childs":["Fritz","Julia"],
     "address":
     {
         "streetAddress": "21 Pilatusstrasse",
         "city": "Lucerne",
         "postalCode": "6000"
     },

 }
```

Its clear that the first 3 entries are name/value pairs and the 4th is a list.
But what exactly is the 5th entry "address"?
Is this seen as a name/value pair, where its value is a JSON object which itself again contains name/value pairs?

Thanks for the quick enlightning.

Comment: its just a nested object.

Comment: have a look here: http://json.org/

Comment: @HerrDerb - And you can also go for this most useful link -
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLc7STlqyZm1rd7UI6xV0lNUvVXFmRjxSC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the categorization scheme you cited, the 5th entry, "address", is a name-value pair. What makes the 5th different from the 1st to 3rd is that the value in the 5th is not a primitive type (number or string), but a JSON object itself. It can be called a nested object.

The 4th one is strictly speaking a name-value pair as well. It is just that its value is an ordered list.

To fall into the category of "ordered list", the JSON needs to start with "[", which is allowed in JSON.

See: [can a JSON start with [?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034444/can-a-json-start-with)