# C# Parse Json string into Array (equivalent of Json.parse in Javascript)

Tags: c#

I have following string.

`string jsonString = "[['Angelica','Ramos'],['Ashton','Cox']]";`

I want to parse it into `Javascript` array like

```
[
    [
        "Angelica",
        "Ramos"
    ],
    [
        "Ashton",
        "Cox"
    ]
]
```

similar to `Json.parse` command. Any idea how to do this with .NET?

I tried both

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString)
```

and

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(jsonString)
```

but no luck so far

UPDATE ANSWER :

`Oluwafemi` answer is correct, here's the example between `Oluwafemi` answer and `WHOl`

[image]

Comment: You *can't* parse it "into a JavaScript array", because you're not using JavaScript.. also the "string" shown is JavaScript (or broken C#), *not* JSON. A finally, the problem description - "no luck so far" - is non-existent.

Comment: Your jsonString is an array, not a string. You could try http://www.newtonsoft.com/json. Or maybe pass it in as an object, instead of an array. So put 'jsonObject = ' at the beginning.

Comment: did you mean             var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<object>>>(json); ?

Comment: @user2864740: I believe it's a valid JSON because datatables plugin expect this format.

Comment: @warheat1990 It is still not valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/) - nor does the string literal inside the "following string" represent valid JSON.

Comment: @user2864740: why not? You can copy the string and paste it to any online JSON converter and it will recognize is as a valid JSON.

Comment: Please visit the link provided to the JSON grammar rules and/or use a JSON linter. But enough [trying to correct all the wrong on the internet](https://xkcd.com/386/) ..

Comment: @user2864740: I don't mean to be a jackass, but what am I suppose to look in that page? Is it because my Json start with square bracket? I'm not trying to correct anything, just honest question, it seems like you're getting salty though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034444/can-a-json-start-with

Comment: The railroad tracks - for string :) The *only* valid string (or key, and which is required to be quoted) quote in JSON is a double quote. The RFC JSON updates allow any JSON value to be the root value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a 2 dimension array and to get this to work you need to do it this way:

```
string result = @"[['Angelica','Ramos'],['Ashton','Cox']]";
string[][] arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(result);
```

Comment: works thanks! please see my updated post to compare between your answer and WHol

Comment: @user2864740 I have just updated my answer with a valid json.

Comment: Still wrong on the replace.. and without the dubious text replace it is *still* [invalid JSON](http://www.json.org/). JSON is a very specific format. Anything else is .. something else, leniency in parsing aside.

Comment: The problem with the original string literal is `@"foo\bar" == "foo\\bar"`. The slash has *no meaning* in a verbatim string literal.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

Try this

```
string jsonString = "[[\"Angelica\",\"Ramos\"],[\"Ashton\",\"Cox\"]]";
JArray ja = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonString);
```

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm