# what is the purpose of using square brackets in json?

Tags: json, square-bracket

I am new to json. Some json examples i have seen have data within the curly braces and some json examples have subdata within square brackets.

```
{
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

From http://json.org/example.html

What is the need/purpose of having data within the square brackets?

regards

Comment: @Quentin my question differed from the question suggested as duplicate.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You are asking what the difference between `[]` and `{}` is, that question is asking what the difference between `[]`, `{}` and `new Array()` is. That's as close to identical as makes no practical difference.

Comment: @Quentin Maybe. I thought [ ] **within** { } had a different significance. No problemo, i got it now.

Comment: The distinction of using a JSON example was important to me. I suppose it's ok to be marked a dupe as long as the question remains available.

Comment: What a weak reason for something to be a duplicate... I see where that's coming from, but that assumes you know that javascript and json are practically the same thing, otherwise it will seem odd.

Comment: This explains things in great detail and thoroughly answers the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034547/1854328

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The square brackets produce a list/array.

The curly brackets produce an object with key/value pairs.

The list can then be a value of a key/value pair.

Comment: doesn't the "product" depends on the implementation of deserializing function in each language ? Isn't json just a few rules for plain text ? I thought only programming languages can have rules for "producing datatypes or objects"

Answer (score 64):

`[]` means an array of object (a list)
and `{}` means it will be an object.

Example:

```
{
    "ID":"test",
    "sports": [
        "volley-ball",
        "badminton"
    ]
}
```

To get the ID, you can do: `myjsonobject.ID` (here you will get "test")

And for sports: `myjsonobject.sports[0]` (here you will get "volley-ball")

Comment: The example makes the concept of { } and [ ] clear. Thanks!

Comment: In other words, [ ] is an array, and { } is a hashtable. For the PowerShell guys, [ ] equals @( ), while { } equals @{ }.