# Deserialize JSON with square brackets around string values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, json.net

I receive the following JSON from a Web API that lists the errors that were found in a POST. There can be more than one key-value pair in `ModelState`, depending how many errors were found. The only problem is that there are square brackets around the values. So when I deserialize with JSON.net there is an `Unexpected token` error.

My solution now is to do a search and replace for those brackets and then deserialize, which does work. But is there a better solution?

**My class**

```
public class Error
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> ModelState { get; set; }
}
```

**The JSON**

```
{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "member.Gender": ["An error has occurred."],
        "member.MemberID": ["The MemberID field is required."],
        "member.BoardMemberID": ["The BoardMemberID field is required."],
    }
}
```

**How I deserialize now**

```
Error error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Error>(jsonString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""));
```

Comment: [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688321/what-is-the-purose-of-using-square-brackets-in-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will want ModelState to be a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` instead of `Dictionary<string, string>`

i.e.

```
public class Error
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> ModelState { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Accepted your answer as the correct one since all thee are almost identical, but yours was the first.

Answer (score 3):

just  change your model to  the following

```
public class Error
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string[]> ModelState { get; set; }
    }
```

and the deserialization will  look like the following

```
Error error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Error>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish your task, modify the Error class in the following manner:

```
public class Error
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> ModelState { get; set; }
}
```