# using fetch with express and ejs gives 400 bad request aswell as unexpected token < in json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Using fetch I'm getting a bad request as well as unexpected token < in JSON both point to search.js which is where I'm making the fetch request I have tried sending via an API client and it is working I'm trying to send the fetch request via input onkeyup.
Also noticed my error is uncaught

Fetch req:

```
const searchResults =  function(e){
fetch('/elpers/search' ,
{
 method: 'POST', 
 headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
 body: JSON.stringify(e.value)
}).then(res => {
  res.json()
}).then(data => {
 console.log(data)
}).catch(err => {
console.error(err)
})
}
```

POST route

```
 const postSearch = (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body)
res.send({'result': 'value'});
}
```

edit: this worked for me `JSON.stringify({result: e.value})`

Error:

`search.js:2 POST http://localhost:3000/elpers/search 400 (Bad Request) VM118:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: The `unexpected token <` error, in my experiences, often indicates that an API call resulted in something other than JSON (usually HTML) in the response. That's probably happening because the `.then` is being called which is trying to do `res.json()`. Fetch does not throw an error when the response status code is 400. You should figure out why it's resulting in a 400 Bad Request from the API, as well as check for a valid response status code in `.then`.

Comment: try to remove than() . you are using tww then in function remove data then().

Comment: @Matt U uh i'm receiving a text/htmt even though im try to send a json response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821751/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0)

Comment: @Jared Smith i don't know how i would apply the accepted answer I'm running the server on localhost

Comment: @pymdarc this is a super common error when parsing JSON in Javascript (especially when dealing with server responses). Just as is said in the top answers on that linked dupe, you're getting HTML back from your server instead of JSON. The usual culprit is the 404 page because the front end API call doesn't match the route defined on the server. In your particular case it looks like your fetch for `/elpers/search` might be missing an 'h'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `res.json()` instead of `res.send()` and `JSON.stringify(e.value)` to `JSON.stringify({result: e.value})`

Comment: this still gives the same err and the response is still text/html

Comment: the postSearch method should also be async.

Comment: then that should mean that the error is triggered from JSON.stringify(e.value) e.value should be a json else it will throw an error.

Comment: Im using html input to get the e.value does JSON.stringify not make it JSON?

Comment: no that is not the case to make it json you can do something like `{ value: e.value}`. `JSON.stringify` takes a json and converts it to a string

Comment: thanks this gave me the solution which was ```JSON.stringify({result: e.value})```

Answer (score 0):

use this ans let me know:

```
 const postSearch = (req, res) => {
     console.log(req.body)   // post if data is received here...
     res.json({
        message: "data received!",
        data: search,        // search should be the data that user fetched
    })
};
```

On the client side, just console.log the data received and see if it is JSON or not :)))

Happy coding!

Comment: i don't think the fetch request is reaching the route because it isn't logging the req.body the errors are the same

Comment: If you're not reaching the route, you won't receive anything, maybe that's where the problem is. If you're using ExpressJS, try a simple route from the backend like this. `app.post(/route, (req, res) => {console.log(req.body}; res.json({message: "data received!"}));`

Comment: Nope its still not reaching the route does fetch works differently with localhost?

Comment: No, try to put the entire localhost in the request url. example: "http://localhost:8080/elpers/search". Make sure the link is correct.

Comment: nope same thing also even before using the whole route the post route did try sending it to http://localhost:3000/elpers/search

Comment: If nothing shows on the express console, check your backend code or post it.

Comment: by post it if you mean form submit then it works and its logs on the console so would that mean the backend is working?

Comment: Does the log contains the data the server is supposed to send? then yes. by post, i meant "show us the code" lol

Comment: Oh my bad ```app.post('/route', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
 res.json({message: "data received!"})
});``` Route and fetch : ```const searchResults = function(e){
fetch('http://localhost:3000/route' ,{
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
 body: JSON.stringify(e.value)
}).then(res => {
console.log(res)
console.log(res.status)
  res.json()
}).then(data =>
{ console.log(data)
}).catch(err => {
console.error(err)
})
}```  sorry for the bad format

Comment: Make one promise on the client side and console.log(res) only, what comes from that?

Comment: promise seems to work on its own and if you meant fetch promise i tried a get request on /elpers and it works aswell

Comment: GET and POST are two different things, when you send the post request above, what do you get on console.log(res)?

Comment: I get the response object on the console with status 400 is there something more specific in it you need to know??

Comment: ```JSON.stringify({result: e.value}) ``` this worked for me i don't why it didn't when i sent an object like so ```{'result: 'value'}```