# json4s - parsing fails for simple String value

Tags: json, scala, json4s

Why the encoding works for `"bla-b"` but not the parsing ?

```
scala> import org.json4s._
import org.json4s._

scala> import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

scala> import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._


scala> parse(compact(render("bla-b")))
org.json4s.ParserUtil$ParseException: expected field or array
Near: "bla-b"
  at org.json4s.native.JsonParser$Parser.fail(JsonParser.scala:207)
  at org.json4s.native.JsonParser$$anonfun$1.newValue$1(JsonParser.scala:155)
  at org.json4s.native.JsonParser$$anonfun$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:164)
  at org.json4s.native.JsonParser$$anonfun$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:117)
  at org.json4s.native.JsonParser$.parse(JsonParser.scala:105)
  at org.json4s.native.JsonParser$.parse(JsonParser.scala:53)
  at org.json4s.native.JsonMethods$class.parse(JsonMethods.scala:11)
  at org.json4s.native.JsonMethods$.parse(JsonMethods.scala:62)
  ... 35 elided

scala> compact(render("bla-b"))
res9: String = "bla-b"
```

On the other hand, this runs without errors:

```
scala> parse(compact(render("joco" -> "bla-b")))
res5: org.json4s.JValue = JObject(List((joco,JString(bla-b))))
```

Answer (score 3):

As said in [docs](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#parsing-json) for `org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.parse()`:

> Any valid json can be parsed into internal AST format

A valid JSON is either a collection of name/value pairs (object) or an ordered list of values (array). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034547/746347) for more details.

`bla-b` is not a valid JSON. But `["bla-b"]` or `{"joco":"bla-b"}` is a valid JSON.

For some reason `org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.render()` can render not only `JObject` or `JArray` but also other `JValue` instances like `JString` so it can produce invalid JSON. I suggest to ask developers about that ([you already did](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/439)).

So you render `bla-b` to invalid JSON, then you are trying to parse it and you get this error.