# Posting Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

First, I want to thank stack overflow before posting this. Here's the scenario. I want to Post Array [["a","b"],["c","d"]] in javascript. And Return data as the same [["a","b"],["c","d"]]. But I got these value - "[[\"a\",\"b\"],[\"c\",\"d\"]]"

Thanks in advance.

**var arraylist = [["a","b"],["c","d"]];**

```
$.ajax({
async: true,
type: "POST",
url: "/TestReciever.cshtml",
data: JSON.stringify(arraylist),
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
    }            
});
```

**My TestReciever.cshtml code is :**

```
string input;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream)){
input = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
var j = Json.Encode(input);
Response.Write(j);
```

Comment: It is because you have encoded the string input `Json.Encode(input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
string input;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream)){
input = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
// Your are encoding the JSON data to STRING 
   var j = Json.Encode(input);  // Its like doing JSON.stringify in JS
   Response.Write(j);
```

This line `var j = Json.Encode(input);` is converting your JSON to an string. what its doing in your code is that as your JSON consist of **double quotes** in its structure. so, its basically escapes them. like  from `[["a","b"],["c","d"]]` to `"[[\"a\",\"b\"],[\"c\",\"d\"]]"`;

In javascript you need to do `JSON.parse(YOUR_RESPONSE)` to read the data as a array.

```
$.ajax({
async: true,
type: "POST",
url: "/TestReciever.cshtml",
data: JSON.stringify(arraylist),
success: function (data) {
       var your_array = JSON.parse(data); //This will parse your string to ARRAY
       /* NOW USE YOUR ARRAY HERE AS A NORMAL ARRAY*/
    }            
});
```

For more information on [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the
>   JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional
>   reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the
>   resulting object before it is returned.

If your are confused if array can be a JSON here is an great [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034444/can-a-json-start-with)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is in the cs-code, not the javascript. The line `var j = Json.Encode(input);` will json-encode the already json-encoded string coming from your site. If you simply return your input, you should get the correct json back.

Comment: @ jonasfh, @Nadir Laskar , Thanks I already understood. Thanks for the explanation and time. I will now try another scenario again. It help me a lot.