# create hive table from json

Tags: json, hive

I wanted to Create hive table with Json array
I am facing issue with top level array. can anyone suggest me a solution.
My json object looks like below

```
  [{"user_id": "a"," previous_user_id": "b"},{"user_id": "c"," previous_user_id": "d"},{"user_id": "e"," previous_user_id": "f"}]
```

Hive command to create the table:

```
create external table array_tmp (User array<struct<user_id: String, previous_user_id:String>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
```

`select user.user_id from array_tmp` gives exception as

> Row is not a valid JSON Object.

I have added the jar ADD JAR *json-serde-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar*;
 Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to make few changes.  Here is an example

myjson/data.json

```
{"users":[{"user_id": "a"," previous_user_id": "b"},{"user_id": "c"," previous_user_id": "d"},{"user_id": "e"," previous_user_id": "f"}]}
```

Now create a Hive table

```
ADD JAR /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-core.jar;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tbl( users array<struct<user_id:string,previous_user_id:string>>) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe" 
location '/user/cloudera/myjson';
```

Do a select

```
select users.user_id from tbl;

+----------------+--+
|    user_id     |
+----------------+--+
| ["a","c","e"]  |
+----------------+--+
```

Comment: I get json object from different team and will not be able to change the json file. The json file has top level arrays and it is a valid json. Is there a way to handle the top level arrays in a json without changing the json object

Comment: @Sindhu: it is a valid json but not a properly designed one.  Check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034444/can-json-start-with