# Accessing an element in json response(array)

Tags: php, json, behat

I have two different(separate) json format response and I am doing a search for element with values in each.

Using this method to evaluate if the expression is valid/invalid:

```
public function evaluate(Json $json, $expression)
{
    if ($this->evaluationMode === 'javascript') {
        $expression = str_replace('->', '.', $expression);
    }
    try {
        return $json->read($expression, $this->propertyAccessor);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Failed to evaluate expression "%s"', $expression), 0, $e);
    }
}
```

One example starts with a curly braces which I believe an [object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034547/8031952).

```
{
    "nid": [
        {
            "value": 10278
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

and I was able to access the `nid` value by typing `nid[0].value`

However, when I have a json response that is enclosed in `[]`:

```
[
    {
        "test": "test",
        "title": "title"
    },
    ...
]
```

I dont get a valid expression when I try `test`

**Other examples** that is valid and invalid:

**VALID** by accessing `data.type`, displays `article`

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "article",
        "id": "123",
    ...
    }
}
```

**INVALID** expression, tried `id[0].value` or `id.value`

```
[
    {
        "id": [
            {
                "value": 398
            }
        ],
    ...
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need values from a Json string then you can use `json-decode` to create an array from Json, or you could extract the values from the Json string using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

`[
   {...},
   {...}
]`

is a jsonArray and

`{
 ...,
 ...
}`

is a json object.

Try accessing json object from json array using getJSONObject(index) method on jsonArray and then you can access values inside json object.