# Deserialize json array using StreamReader

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
[
    [value1, value2, value3]
    [value2, value2, value3]
    ...
]
```

I've tried to use both

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/TempData/CapitalSparesBucketsTableData.json")))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            JavascriptSerialzer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer()
            var r  = ser.Deserialize<ResultList>(json);

        }
```

and

```
  using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/TempData/searchData.json")))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            List<SearchResult> searchResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SearchResult>>(json);
        }
```

and I get errors using both methods.

My model looks like this:

```
public class SearchResults
{
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    public SearchResult[] Results { get; set; }
}

public class ResultList
{
    public SearchResult record;
}



public class SearchResult
    {
        public SearchResult() { }
        public SearchResult(IDataReader reader)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (reader)
        {
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
    }

    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    public string Value4 { get; set; }
    public string Value5 { get; set; }
    public string Value6 { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: That doesn't look like a JSON file.

Comment: Please provide a plausible json example

Comment: It's valid. Unusual, but valid. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034444/can-json-start-with

Comment: Try to put break points and find out exactly which line is giving the error, and please provide the specific error text.

Comment: @Fabio it is a valid json.  It's what I have to work with.  If it was in the normal key: value pair format, this would be a non issue.

Comment: Hi, I've edited your title. I know why you did it, but please don't use tags to disambiguate the title - look for other ways to make it distinct. Thanks :)

Comment: @RobM it's valid without comma? From model i assume the values are strings, so he needs quotation marks. If he get errors could be the json is bad formatted

Comment: @slugster maybe I didn't understand correctly, but if you want a model you should have keys / values, otherwise you only have lists in lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, looks like a Jagged Array. I tried this and it worked with .Net Core 2.2.

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>>("[['value'],['value']]");
```

Obs.: couldn't find any question that is exactly like this question.

Comment: Thanks. This worked.  now I just need to massage it into a model.

Comment: Nice work spartanroger .
I am still curious though why desalinizing directly to the model did not work.
Maybe @Rob M  you can still provide us with the error message so that we can help serialize into the model.   
I am thinking that you need to provide values for each of your model properties