# paring json with top level array

Tags: python, json, parsing

I need to parse a json with top level array but I am getting following error. I can remove the top level [] but I guess there should be an easy way I am missing.

**File contents:**

`[{"name": "Bob", "languages": ["English", "Fench"]}]`

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'json'
```

**Code:**

```
data = json.load(json_file)
links = data.json()
```

Comment: you can't have list as top level in json. encapsulate it in another curly brace and then read this.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: can you add what is your expected output

Comment: If you have a list on top level, then it's not JSON.

Comment: @Pbd, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034444/can-json-start-with

Comment: @revliscano, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034444/can-json-start-with

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, added dummy top level element and parsed:

```
data = '{"persons":'+file.read(json_file)+'}'
personsdict = json.loads(data)
print(packagedict['persons'][0]['languages'])
```