# JSON.parse() not failing when it should fail

Tags: node.js, json, buffer

I have the following NodeJS code:

```
const msg = Buffer.from([ 34, 115, 106, 100, 104, 34 ]);
const a = JSON.parse(msg.toString('utf-8'))
console.log(a);
```

The msg buffer is basically the string "sjdh" when using .toString('utf-8') on it.

How come when I run this, JSON.parse is able to parse what is essentially the string "sjdh" and returns it as a result to a?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can JSON start with "\["?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034444/can-json-start-with)

Comment: An array is valid JSON, according to the docs and duplicate above.

Comment: Why is it an array though? Isn't the buffer being converted to a plain string "sdjh" when using .toString('utf-8')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some types are allowed to not be wrapped in an object or array by `JSON.parse`

Read more here [What is the minimum valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json)

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('"asdad"'))
console.log(JSON.parse('null'))
```

Comment: I see! Interesting, so it treats it as a single JSON string which is why it's valid.
Well then how should I avoid this? Remove the " characters after using .toString()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3710506 you can also just check after parsing if it's an array or object